# How do I create an Active X control for use in Internet Explorer 7+?

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, activex

I'm using Delphi 2007 and I am looking for some resources and best practices for writing an ActiveX control for embedding within Internet Explorer 7.0 (and higher).

My goal with this ActiveX control is to be able to retrieve information about which websites the user is visiting, and the type of connection (e.g. HTTPS, HTTP, FTP, etc). I'm not looking to sniff traffic, just for reviewing the addresses they are visiting.

Or, if it would be easier, I would ideally like to write a toolbar similar to AVG Anti-Virus' free toolbar that it installs in IE that "verifies" links on pages as safe links. If you have any suggestions, please let me know.

Regards.

Comment: "I'm not looking to sniff traffic, just for reviewing the addresses they are visiting."  How are those two things different?

Comment: One is sniffing the traffic, the other is knowing where they are going. For example, if you drove a car from your house to the Mall and told me, that would be different than if I put a bug in your car and recorded your conversation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a new project, you can choose several options, one of them is an ActiveX control.

I have done that in the past (delphi 7) and used it on a web page without problems.